# How to get a list of programs which are using same physical file in As400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

For example, if TESTPF is a file and and it is used in PGM1, PGM2..... PGM10. And If I want to get a list of all these programs name, Is there any command or method to get the list ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The command is `DSPPGMREF`. This command returns (either to the screen, or an outfile) all the programs and files that a program references. You can run this command over all the programs in a library with output to a file, and then query the file to find all programs that reference a given file.

```
DSPPGMREF PGM(MYLIB/*ALL)        
          OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)       
          OBJTYPE(*ALL)          
          OUTFILE(MYLIB/MYLIBREF)
```

Then:

```
SELECT WHLIB, WHPNAM
FROM MYLIB/MYLIBREF
WHERE WHFNAM = 'TESTPF'
```

NOTE: If you are using logical files, the referenced file name will be the logical file, not the physical file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Display Program References (DSPPGMREF)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/dsppgmref.htm) command.

Output the results to a file, `OUTPUT(*FILE)` and you can use SQL to query it.